# PHP - if else not working in date operation

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I have logical problem with `if...else` in PHP that using date in operation.

What I want is:

- if `$jd` less than `$jam` printout 'red'
- if between `$jam` and `$jam` plus 2 hours printout 'green',
- if `$jd` more than `$h1` printout 'white'.

This is the source code:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');  
$jam = Date('H:i'); 
$jd = '12:00:00';
$h1 = $jd + 2;

if ($jd > $h1){     
    echo 'white'; 
} elseif ($jd < $h1) {  
    if ($jd > $jam) {
        echo 'green';
    } else {
        echo 'red';
    }    
}
```

The problem is the `$jd` value more than `$jam` plus 2 hours it's printout 'green' instead 'white'.

It seems doesn't work with date operation, but with number it's working.

Answer (score 1):

When your comparisons involve dates, you should use DateTime objects. You were dealing with dates and times as they were string and comparing them directly.

This is an example as close as possible to your code, to show how you should create `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects and how to compare and use them with each other.

The demo uses:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.construct
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring

```
<?php
    //$jam holds the now datetime(Immutable) (as object.. not as string!)
    $jam = new DateTimeImmutable();

    //jd holds a a datetime containing now (where the time part is 12:00:00 as specified in hh:mm:ss format)
    $jd = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '12:00:00');
    
    //puts in $h1: $jam+2hours (that's why we used DateTimeImmutable instead of DateTime
    //otherwise the add method would have altered directly the calling object $jam)
    $h1 = $jam->add( DateInterval::createFromDateString('2 hours') );
    
    //this is an example on how to convert those datetime to string and print to screen
    echo $jam->format('H:i');
    echo $h1->format('D M j, Y G:i:s T');
    
    //here you are doing comparisons between full datetimes (including the date parts)
    
    if ($jd > $h1){     
        echo 'white'; 
    } else if ($jd < $h1) {  
        if ($jd > $jam) {
            echo 'green';
        } else {
            echo 'red';
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is better to work with DateTime. DateTime objects are directly comparable, so formatting can be omitted.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

$staticTime = '12:00:00';
$dt = date_create($staticTime);
$now = date_create('now');

$color =  'green';
if($dt < $now) {
  $color =  'red';
}
elseif($dt > date_create('now +2 hours')) {
  $color = 'white';
}

echo 'At '.$now->format('H:i').' Color='.$color;
```

new DateTime() or [date_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) also understands many expressions like 'now + 2 hours' directly.

Try it self on https://3v4l.org/bebSt

Answer (score -1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$staticTime = '12:00:00';
$jam = strtotime(date('H:i'));
$jd = strtotime($staticTime); 
$h1 = strtotime($jam . " +2hours");

if($jd < $jam) {
    echo 'red';
} else if($jd > $jam && $jd < $h1 ) {
    echo 'green';
} else if($jd > $h1) {
    echo 'white';
}
```

convert the time to strtotime to compare

Comment: its work for the red and white but not the green.

so i try to modified the code.
```php
> date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
> $staticTime = '5:00:00';
> $jam = strtotime(date('H:i'));
> $jd = strtotime($staticTime); 
> $h1 = strtotime($staticTime . " +2 hours");
> $h2 = strtotime($staticTime . " --2 hours");
> 
> if($jam > $jd && $jam < $h1 ){
>   echo 'green';
> }elseif ($h2 < $jam){
>     echo 'red';
> }else {
>   echo 'white';
> }
```
It working now.

Thank you. ^_^

Comment: ```php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$staticTime = '5:00:00';
$jam = strtotime(date('H:i'));
$jd = strtotime($staticTime); 
$h1 = strtotime($staticTime . " +2 hours");
$h2 = strtotime($staticTime . " --2 hours");
 
if($jam > $jd && $jam < $h1 ){
 echo 'green';
}elseif ($h2 < $jam){
    echo 'red';
}else {
 echo 'white';
}
```